# Failed to Perform dissociation handshake for TOE

Tags: networking

Failed to Perform dissociation handshake for TOE initialization. TOE capabiltity is disabled for Embedded NIC 2.

I ran updates and this starting coming up on 12.04LTS. I cant get either NIC to work and I found some ideas on google but they all require ethtool which I dont have installed and have no NIC for a connection. I even tried 13.02 usb boot and also didn't see the NICs. Am I having a hardware failure?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem for my dell poweredge 2970. the nic that's failing for me is NIC1, but it tells me the same thing. I just recently replaced the motherboard, and this error keep coming every time I boot, no matter what I try. You can actually go into BIOS and turn your nics back onto the TOE setting, but it doesn't fix the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the TOE key from my motherboard, which is right next to the sideplane and power interfaces. I reenabled my NICs in bios, as you obviously can't use the server if it isn't networked in.

This has effectively solved my problem combined with the information I put before.

New mobos don't support TOE, so remove the key, and reenable the NICs.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu on a 2950 and ran into this problem. As a result, I removed the TOEkey but I did not disable the NICs in the bios before removing the key- should I have? What am I missing? The problem persists without the TOEkey. Thanks in advance.